# Editing PHP grid page for WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to Edit the Grid Artist page to only have 12 artists and land on the producers section instead of all artist.

Here' s the link of website page : http://cascaderecords.fr/roster/

PHP code:

```
<?php
if (ci_setting('artists_isotope') == 'enabled' AND !wp_is_mobile() AND !is_tax() ):
    ?>
    <ul class="filters-nav group">
        <li><a href="#filter" class="selected" data-filter="*"><?php _e('All Artists', 'ci_theme'); ?></a></li>
        <?php
            $args = array('hide_empty' => 1);
            $cats = get_terms('artist-category', $args);
        ?>
        <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ): ?>
            <li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
endif; // is isotope enabled

global $paged;
if ( ci_setting('artists_isotope') == 'enabled' AND !wp_is_mobile() AND !is_tax() ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt_artists',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
}   else {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt_artists',
        'posts_per_page' => ci_setting('artists_per_page'),
        'paged' => $paged
    );
}

$the_query = !empty($the_query) ? $the_query : new WP_Query($args);
?>



<article class="row">
<ul class="col-md-12 items-list-grid filter-container <?php echo $filter; ?>">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $cats = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'artist-category'); ?>

        <li class="<?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ) : echo $cat->slug.' '; endforeach; echo $grid;  ?>">
            <article id="artist-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('row'); ?>>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <figure>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('ci_thumb_square'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </figure>
                    <?php endif; ?>


                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
            </article><!-- /row -->
        </li><!-- /col-md-4 -->
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: please check all assigned to artist

Answer (score 0):

Try change:

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

to:

```
'posts_per_page' => 12
```

Not sure what "ci_setting('artists_per_page')" is in below variable, need more info:

```
'posts_per_page' => ci_setting('artists_per_page'),
```

Comment: Thanks  for your reply !

Comment: I want  also to remove the filter all artist and arrive on the filter artists when we arrive in the artists section of the site